# Multiple clickable JPanels

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel

I've currently got 108 auto generated jPanels, each containting a random number.
Is there a way to easily make each of these clickable? 
Here's my code..

Creating JPanels:

```
        for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++) 
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < numbers[row].length; col++) 
            {
                int tempNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
                numbers[row][col] = tempNumber;
                np1 = new NumberPanel(tempNumber);
                np1.setLocation(row*np1.getWidth(), row*getWidth());
                add(np1);
            }        
    }
```

The number panel class:

```
     public NumberPanel(int randomNumber)
{
    String number = Integer.toString(randomNumber);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    setBackground(Color.red);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(number, JLabel.LEFT);
    label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 35));
    add(label);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a panel to contain a JLabel? Why not just add the label directly to the parent panel?

Instead of using a `JLabel` to display the random number use a `JButton`. Then you can add an `ActionListener` to each of the buttons.

You can make the button look like a label by using:

```
button.setBorderPainted( false );
```

So basically, instead of creating 108 panels that contain a JLabel, you just create 108 JButtons and add the buttons directly to the parent panel.

Comment: I can do buttons.. But because they're created through a loop, how would I go about having a mouse click?

Comment: I already stated that you would add an `ActionListener` to the buttons. You can add the same ActionListener to every button. In the ActionListener code you use the `getSource()` method of the `ActionEvent` to get the button that was clicked.

Comment: I get that, but how will it actually know which button seeing as won't they all be created with the same name 'np1'?

Comment: @Liam Use `getActionCommand` from the `ActionEvent` passed to the `actionPeformed` method or cast the source of the `ActionEvent` to a `JButton` and use `getText`.  Alterntivly, you could place the buttons in an array or `List` and look them up (comparing the source of the `ActionEvent` with those elements in the list)

Comment: `but how will it actually know which button` - I already stated that the `getSource()` method will return the button that was clicked. All you need to do is cast the object to a JButton. ie. `JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource();`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you should avoid using Absolute Position Layout (null layout). As you already know the number of rows and columns, it would be easier to have a GridLayout and keep adding components accordingly.

On the other hand, just add an ActionListener and use the getSource() from the Event to get whatever was clicked. With the panel (or label) clicked, you can get the Text to know whats its value.

Assuming the ActionListener was added to the JLabel, you can do:

```
if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
  Integer value = Integer.valueOf(((JLabel) evt.getSource()).getText());
}
```

I actually like more the idea to have everything decoupled, so I'll just send a FirePropertyChange and receive it wherever I need to process the value.

Comment: `Assuming the ActionListener was added to the JLabel` - you can't add an ActionListener to a JLabel.  `just add an ActionListener and use the getSource() from the Event` - as has already been suggested, although the OP also would need to use a JButton for this so you can use an ActionListener.

Comment: You are right, I was meant to say MouseListener (MouseAdapter->MouseClicked) if its the case he wants to use a JLabel. thx for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

If NumberPanel extends from JPanel, inside the constructor you can add Mouse listener.

addMouseListener(new MouseListener() { 
....
});

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have clickable `JPanel` with saved "state" you can use `JToggleButton`:

```
public class NumberButton extends JToggleButton {

public NumberButton(int randomNumber) {
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    String number = Integer.toString(randomNumber);
    setText(number);
    setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 35));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    setBackground(Color.red);
}
```

}